# Как можно сократить количество кода в программе на android?

Tags: android

Вероятнее всего ответов на такие вопросы есть море, может даже на CO, но я не нашел ответ на интересующий меня вопрос. У меня в программе осуществляются запросы на сервер, и в каждом запросе я прописываю такой кусок кода:

```
sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("url", 0);
        String url = sp.getString("url", "");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        adapter = null;

        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("access_token", 0);
        String a_token = sp.getString("access_token", "");

        final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

так как запросов уже многовато, то появилось желание как-то убрать этот кусок. Может можно сделать свое какое-то регулярное выражение, или свой регулярный кусок кода, в котором можно было бы прописать это. Мне почему-то кажется что делать нужно через класс, не знаю почему но кажется.

Может кто знает как убрать этот кусок, где-то его прописать один раз и дальше вызывать постоянно что-то(пока не очень понял что именно нужно будет вызывать).

Comment: что то слышали о методах с аргументами? самое время об этом узнать :)

Comment: та я то слышал, но думал просто может можно вообще вынести этот кусок в отдельный файл или что-то типа того)) я методом конечно представляю как сделать, просто думал может есть другой способ какой-то

Comment: какой другой? можете сделать отдельный "утилитный" класс взаимодействия с сетью и в нем написать этот метод. Будет актуально, если запросы выполняются из разных классов

Comment: ну как-бы да запросы выполняются из разных классов, а это какая-то специальная разновидность класса? потому-что я вот сейчас пробую сделать метод, и могу сделать только, что-бы он возвращал один параметр, то есть получается придется делать два метода, или тот класс который вы назвали

Comment: это такой обычный класс, в котором вы реализовали нужный вам метод. Для того, чтобы возвращал разные параметры у методов есть аргументы

Comment: добавьте в вопрос несколько частей кода, которые возвращают разные параметры и которые вы хотите объединить в один метод

Comment: честно говоря, я плохо понимаю какой код вы хотите увидеть, я могу добавить в вопрос только мои кривые попытки сделать метод который возвращает объект ретрофита, я просто попробовал сделать такой метод но у меня потом не получилось из него вызвать нужный мне метод

Comment: вы пишите *"..так как запросов уже многовато .."* - приведите несколько примеров таких разных запросов, которые вы хотите объединить в один метод

Comment: я хотел этой фразой сказать, что указанный в вопросе кусок кода используется очень часто, и поэтому я хочу сделать один раз в классе метод, и потом его вызывать когда нужно. Я дополнил вопрос, вроде метод работает)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот мой кусок кода который я хочу убрать, и вызывать просто метод:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("url", 0);
String url = sp.getString("url", "");

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build();

return retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

вот я вызываю метод при запросе:

```
APIService mAPIService2 = apiService();
```

я проверил все вроде работает. Надеюсь кому-то еще поможет :)